# The iptables problem with NAT under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, network-protocols, iptables

Greet Everybody
I have some problems about iptables rules under Ubuntu .

I create a simple firewall with the function of NAT,then restart the server.
the command to create:

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

type commands below in the terminal:

```
iptables -L -v
```

But display no rules.
And it seemd that the NAT function and the rules made last time are still available to use.

Is it necessary to create some script to save the rules .
Will the rules got lost when I restart the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

iptables by default lists filter rules. Use

```
iptables -t nat -L
```

to see NAT rules.